# OpenVAS: This CPE does not appear in the CPE dictionary but is referenced by one or more CVE

Tags: openvas

Any ideas on what may be causing this message to appear when following the link from "Detected Applications"?

> This CPE does not appear in the CPE dictionary but is referenced by
>   one or more CVE.

This happens even when following (for example): `cpe:/o:microsoft:windows`. I think the CPE dictionary hasn't been set properly, but I'm struggling to diagnose why this may be.

Thanks

Comment: When I Google the error, I see that it is actually a message that is part of the database: https://secinfo.greenbone.net/omp?r=1&cmd=get_info&info_type=cpe&info_name=cpe:/a:postgresql:postgresql:7.2.1&details=1&token=guest

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same issue using OpenVAS on Kali Linux from behind a firewall that doesn't allow the rsync protocol outbound. Most of the OpenVAS updates use HTTPS, but one of its databases can only be updated via the rsync protocol.

Look at any firewall logs from between your OpenVAS system and the internet to confirm there are rsync connections being dropped, and if so open it temporarily while running OpenVAS updates.